# Date Now() not going in to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have some code shown below, which inserts date_time and date in to the mysql fields using the now() command.

However the date_time field updates but the date field doesn't and I can not seem to work out why?

my mysql fields are datetime and date

```
   INSERT INTO vistordetails1 
            (ipaddress, client_id, type, date_time, company_name, location, search_term, trafic_source, no_of_pages, date, country_code) VALUES('$ip_address', '$client_id', '$type', now(),'$fields[11]','$fields[6]', '$keyword', '$referer','1', now(), '$country_code')
```

Table Structure

```
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,

    `master_id` int(11) NOT NULL,

    `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL ,

    `date_time` datetime NOT NULL,

    `company_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,

    `location` varchar(250) NOT NULL,

    `no_of_pages` int(11) NOT NULL,

    `trafic_source` varchar(250) NOT NULL,

    `search_term` varchar(250) NOT NULL,

    `is_repeater` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,

    `classification` int(11) NOT NULL,

    `owner` int(11) NOT NULL,

    `alert_for_repeat_visit` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

    `is_hot_list` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

    `ipaddress` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

    `country_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

    `date` date NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Before you write any more SQL code, read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) before you create more of these serious [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: 1. In what way does this not work? What *does* get put in the fields? 2. Echo the query before it's run for debugging purposes, see if it's formed correctly. In addition to SQL injection vulnerability the query will break if there are unescaped single quotes.

Comment: @Simon `NOW()` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Simon **Now()** is a valid MySQL function, why do you recommand doing differently?

Comment: Thanks, noting is placed in to the table, everything else is fine but the date field just keeps the 0000-00-00 format

Comment: can you show us the Table structure?

Comment: I don't see the named **date** field in your table structure ? It's **date_time** you meant ?

Comment: Inserting into a colum called date where date is a protected oO. try `\`date\`` on your left insert

Comment: it is underneath country code, i had to scroll the bar down

Answer (score 0):

Try using CURDATE() instead of NOW() for the date field.

`$INSERT =  "INSERT INTO vistordetails1 
            (ipaddress, 
            client_id, 
            type, 
            date_time, 
            company_name, 
            location, 
            search_term, 
            trafic_source, 
            no_of_pages, 
            date, 
            country_code) 
            VALUES(
            '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($ip_address))."', 
            '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($client_id))."',

            '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($type))."', 
            now(),
            '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($fields[11]))."', 
            '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($fields[6]))."', 
            '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($keyword))."', 
            '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($referer))."', 
            '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim(1))."', 
            CURDATE(), 
            '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($country_code'))."')";`

Also as a previous user mentioned you seriously need to make sure your data is escaped, or use mysql prepare.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert a PHP date into a valid MySql date, then the only thing you need to do is
ensure that it is formatted correctly.

The default `date`/`datetime` format for `Mysql` is: `yyyy-mm-dd` and `yyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

Something like this will work.

`$phpDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());`

**However**

Because you are creating a new date, why use `PHP` at all? Within `MySql` you can include the current date using `NOW()` function.

`$sql = "INSERT INTO xyz (a, b, c, datetime) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', NOW());"`

**Additionally**

You could apply a `default value` of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to the table column. Meaning you wouldn't even need to pass any date
as the database will take care of it.

i.e `ALTER TABLE test CHANGE datecolumn datecolumn DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`